# How can I check duplicate username in a form without posting form

Tags: php, mysql

I have a registration form that requires an email address. We have a problem with duplicate registration so I am trying to check my db to see if an email address already exists. The check seems to happen but I am always getting a response of 0 which I know is not true.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$('#Email').blur(check_email); //use keyup,blur, or change 
}); 

function check_email(){
var emailPR = $('#Email').val();
jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'check_email.php',
        data: emailPR,
        cache: false,
        success: function(response){
            if(response == 0){
               alert('Email address available')
            }
            else {
                 alert(emailPR + ' is already registered ')
                 //do perform other actions like displaying error messages etc.,
            }
        }
    });
}
```

check_email.php:

```
<?php
/*** mysql hostname ***/
$hostname = 'XXX';

/*** mysql username ***/
$username = 'XXX';

/*** mysql password ***/
$password = 'XXX';

/*** mysql databse ***/
$dbname = 'XXX';

try 
{
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=mysql", $username, $password);
    /*** echo a message saying we have connected ***/
    //echo 'Connected to database';
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}   

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT email FROM clients where email = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($_POST['emailPR']));
echo $stmt->rowCount();
?>
```

Here is my updated code as per your amends:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$('#Email').blur(check_email); //use keyup,blur, or change 
}); 

function check_email(){
var emailPR = $('#Email').val();
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'check_email.php',
    data: { emailPR: emailPR }, //emailPR this name you get post value. So it must be same name.
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response){
          alert(response); 
        if(response===true)  {
           alert('Email address available')
        }
        else {
             alert(emailPR + ' is already registered ')
             //do perform other actions like displaying error messages etc.,
        }
    }
});
}
```

email_check.php file contents now:

```
/*** mysql hostname ***/
$hostname = 'xxxxxxx';

/*** mysql username ***/
$username = 'xxxxxx';

/*** mysql password ***/
$password = 'xxxxxxx';

/*** mysql databse ***/
$dbname = 'xxxxxxxx';

try 
{
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=mysql", $username, $password);
    /*** echo a message saying we have connected ***/
    //echo 'Connected to database';
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}   

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT email FROM clients where email = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($_POST['emailPR']));
echo json_encode($stmt->fetchColumn() == 0);
```

Comment: i think the value of emailPR is going empty.
instead of data: emailPR in ajax try this : data: {emailPR:emailPR}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perfectly working fine.

Also use data: { emailPR: emailPR }. You could send also multiple parameters in data in this way.  Try this.

```
        $(document).ready(function(){ 
            $('#customeremail').on('blur', check_email); //use keyup,blur, or change 
        }); 

        function check_email(){
        var emailPR = $('#customeremail').val();
        $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'email_check.php',
                data: { emailPR: emailPR },
                cache: false,
                dataType: 'JSON',
                success: function(response){
                   // alert(response);
                    if(response == 0){
                       alert('Email address available for registration')
                    }
                    else {
                         alert(emailPR + ' is already registered with us')
                         //do perform other actions like displaying error messages etc.,
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Also check like this to test,

```
$emailid = $_POST['emailPR'];

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM clients where email = ?");
    $stmt->execute(array($emailid));
    $number_of_rows = $stmt->fetchColumn(); 
    echo $number_of_rows;

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

See the results.

**Already Registered and available in DB:**

[image]

**New Registration emailid and not available in DB:**

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: The response is always 0 even with your amend. Any suggestions? I thought it might be to do with my sql query and the variable needing to be in quotes as it is an email address being passed through?

Comment: What is the result if you echo $_POST['emailPR']  in check_email.php?

Comment: Whatever I type into the #Email field is returned if I echo $_POST['emailPR']; This is why I think that is something to do with needing quotes around the variable data as it is an email address.

Comment: Are you getting something like xxxxxx@email.com from echo $_POST['emailPR']?

Comment: Yes whatever is typed into the email field is what is returned from echo $_POST['emailPR']

Comment: In check_email.php, can you remove this line, echo $stmt->rowCount(); and instead of this use, echo json_encode($stmt->fetchColumn() == 0);    Because I think, for select rowCount() is not suitable. Mostly it is suitable for update, delete or insert.

Comment: By adding echo json_encode($stmt->fetchColumn() == 0); I get true as the response whether the email address is in the db or not.

Comment: Yes now you could able to write as you wanted, if response===true, then alert('Email address available'). I updated my answer also like this.

Comment: Yes but the response is true whether available or not. If I try something I know is not in the db I get true. If I try something I know is in the db I get true.

Comment: Are you using condition like this?,  if(response===true)  {

Comment: But kuttyraj the response is always true. Something is wrong elsewhere in the code.

Comment: Please check my updated answer. Is it help you anyway? Have you also added, dataType: 'json',?

Comment: I have updated my code to yours above and get no alerts what so ever now.

Comment: The if statement if ($stmt->execute()), just for your testing purpose. And I hope you added dataType: 'json' in ajax as I told you in earlier comment. As per logic, it must be work.

Comment: I have changed my code again to yours above and the response is always true

Comment: I have posted my new code under the original question.

Comment: Any suggestions kuttyraj?

Comment: @PhilRisk Tested in my local with some modifications. And it is working perfect. Please see my updated new code. This will work fine.

Comment: Hi @kuttyraj. That works great. One slight bug/issue I have found as some customers in our DB don't have an email address, it would be nice to error check if blank field give a different error message saying please enter email address as that was in my existing error checking does but is being overridden by this error checking.

Comment: I think its better idea would be choose my answer as right answer as you got to work from solution. And then, if you create a new post for your new error, I could able to look easily instead of we make both comments bigger ;-)

Comment: I solved my bug with some of my existing code. Thanks for all the help it has made my form a lot better. Just a few tweaks to do now.

Comment: I found  a new simple solution for your empty emailid check.    For example, <form id="myform">
    <input type="text" name="email" />
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>                              Then use like this in document.ready jquery,   $('#myform').validate({ 
        rules: {
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            }
        }
    });